# Parse HTML to String in a correct Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically I want to ask that I am working on an ECommerce application in MVC and I have stored the description of `Product` in form of HTML in the database. Now what I have to do is to show that description on `Product Detail` page in such a way that the description should have the correct format as specified in the HTML and `id` the characters of `Description` exceeds 500 characters than to show 'Show More' and 'Show Less' Functionality.

Here is my Code

```
@if (Model.product.FullDescription.Count() > 500)
{
   <p id="fdescription" class="description">
       @Html.Raw(Model.product.FullDescription.Substring(0, 500))
       <a id="showmore" onclick="showdescription(1)"  
           style="color:rgb(0,127,234);cursor:pointer">
                                             Show More</a>
   </p>
   <p id="ffdescription" class="description">
       @Html.Raw(Model.product.FullDescription)
       <a id="showless" onclick="showdescription(2)" 
          style="color:rgb(0,127,234);cursor:pointer">Show Less</a>
   </p>
 }
 else
 {
    <p id="fdescription" class="description">
        @Html.Raw(Model.product.FullDescription)
    </p>
 }
```

but **the issue above is that the 500 characters also counts html tags and the substring function do not parse HTML tags correctly** and some point there ending tags misses.

Comment: Is it necessary to display exactly 500 characters initially. You will find this much easier display one line of text in a div using css styles (`overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;`) and toggle those styles so that the full text is displayed when the button(s) are clicked

Comment: Something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ubxmagy/1/)?

Comment: You could store short description as well and  allow to expand it when long description is present

Answer (score 0):

One way is to parse description to XElement and ask for its value, which return description without tags. This works only if HTML is valid.

XElement descElem = XElement.Parse(descriptionText);
if(descElem.Value <= 500)
{ // save to database}